# C - Character Count from a File

Tags: c, file, count, character

So I want to make a program which counts the occurrences of each character in a file. For example:

4 instances of character 0x67 (g)

11 instances of character 0x68 (h)

and so on

I am not sure how to display and count instances.

Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
const char FILE_NAME[] = "input.txt";
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int             count = 0;  /* number of characters seen */
    FILE           *in_file;    /* input file */

   /* character or EOF flag from input */
    int             ch;

    in_file = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r");
    if (in_file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open %s\n", FILE_NAME);
        exit(8);
    }

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(in_file);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        ++count;
    }
    printf("Number of characters in %s is %d\n",
                  FILE_NAME, count);

    fclose(in_file);
    return (0);
```

Comment: Have you at least worked on how you're going to keep track of counts of each character?

Comment: Well I think I need an array for that and only output the non-zero integers at the end. But...should I use 2 arrays? One for all the characters (256) and one for the occurrences and sync them somehow so that array1[0] = array2[0]?

Comment: Tip: What would happen if you could use the character as an index?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I came up with...

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
  /* a buffer to hold the count of characters 0,...,256; it is
   * initialized to zero on every element */
  int count[256] = { 0 };

  /* loop counter */
  int k;

  /* file handle --- in this case I am parsing this source code */
  FILE *fp = fopen("ccount.c", "r");

  /* a holder for each character (stored as int) */
  int c;

  /* for as long as we can get characters... */
  while((c=fgetc(fp))) {

    /* break if end of file */
    if(c == EOF) break;

    /* otherwise add one to the count of that particular character */
    count[c]+=1;
  }

  /* now print the results; only if the count is different from
   * zero */
  for(k=0; k<256; k++) {
    if(count[k] > 0) {
      printf("char %c: %d times\n", k, count[k]);
    }
  }
  /* close the file */
  fclose(fp);

  /* that's it */
  return 0;
}
```

I compile the code using the following command (GCC 4.8.1 on OS X 10.7.4)

```
gcc ccount.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi
```

it compiles with no warnings and no errors; this is the output:

```
char 
: 40 times
char  : 190 times
char ": 6 times
char #: 2 times
char %: 2 times
char ': 1 times
char (: 11 times
char ): 11 times
char *: 23 times
char +: 3 times
char ,: 5 times
char -: 3 times
char .: 9 times
char /: 20 times
char 0: 5 times
char 1: 1 times
char 2: 3 times
char 5: 3 times
char 6: 3 times
char :: 1 times
char ;: 13 times
char <: 3 times
char =: 7 times
char >: 3 times
char E: 2 times
char F: 2 times
char I: 2 times
char L: 1 times
char O: 1 times
char [: 4 times
char \: 1 times
char ]: 4 times
char a: 29 times
char b: 4 times
char c: 36 times
char d: 15 times
char e: 49 times
char f: 25 times
char g: 4 times
char h: 22 times
char i: 36 times
char k: 9 times
char l: 19 times
char m: 5 times
char n: 35 times
char o: 38 times
char p: 9 times
char r: 34 times
char s: 22 times
char t: 49 times
char u: 16 times
char v: 1 times
char w: 4 times
char y: 2 times
char z: 3 times
char {: 5 times
char }: 5 times
```

Comment: try on real file, it will not work, as it do not init array, use only 128 instead of 256, read from file 2 times each iteration

Comment: Oops... messed up the fgetc... will fix.

Comment: Hey Arrieta! Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't seem to compile correctly:

Comment: In function ‘main’:
part5.c:9: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
part5.c:11: warning: array subscript has type ‘char’

Comment: @MichaelBlue I fixed the warnings (sorry, I wrote the original code in a rush), and added my compiler version and compilation line.

Answer (score 3):

you need to use array, check out:

```
int charArray[256];
memset(charArray, 0, 256*sizeof(int)); // instead of memset, for 0 values you can you just {0}

while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(in_file);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        charArray[ch]++;
    }
for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
    if (charArray[i] > 0)
        printf("Number of character %c is %d\n", (char)i, charArray[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ilya! What's with the memset though? What does it do?

Comment: I don't think thhat charArray should be of chars.  I'd use int charCount[256];

Comment: memset sets all the values to zero.

Comment: Wouldn't `int charArray[256] = {0};` also work to initialise the values to 0?

Comment: @Kninnug no, it will init only first item

Comment: @IlyaBursov: No, it will initialise all elements in the array.

Comment: @IlyaBursov: See section 6.7.8 of the C specification, particularly paragraph 21, which reads *If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration**.*

Comment: @dreamlax check this please, as my compiler (MSVCC) init only first 1

Comment: @dreamlax ok, so it will work for 0, for 1 it will not work, as it set it to 0 too

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I don't understand what you mean, if you use `int array[200] = {0};`, then *all* elements are initialised to 0. C simply requires at least one value in the braces. C++ allows empty braces.

Comment: @dreamlax I've tested this with MSVCC and for int array[200] = {1}; - it initialized only 1st element, also re-read your quote - even standard says that reminder will be inited NOT to first value, but to some default value, which I suppose is 0

Comment: @IlyaBursov: I know this, but why would you want to initialise all elements to 1 in this situation? Even `memset` would be useless in this situation.

Comment: @dreamlax 1 was just an example, real example is 0xff - which can be used for memset to set all values in array, also it is just good tradition to be sure that everything is really inited before use

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve counts of alphabet characters, then it could look like this:

```
int counts[26];
memset(&counts[0], 0, sizeof(counts));

while ( (ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF) {
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
        ++count[ch - 'a'];
}
```

printing them out could be simple as:

```
for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z', ++c)
    printf("Count of '%c' is %d\n", c, count[c - 'a']);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple program I found [here](http://jee-appy.blogspot.in/2015/04/c-program-to-count-number-of-occurance.html) . It takes two input, first the character you want to count and the file name in which the occurrence of character has to be counted.

Answer (score 0):

```
int strchro(char c, char *str) {

    char *pch;
    int found = 0;
    pch=strchr(str,c);
    while (pch!=NULL)
    {
        //printf("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
        found++;
        pch=strchr(pch+1,c);
    }
    return found;
}
```

an old function i wrote a while ago.. hope this helps ;)
more info here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr

Comment: This would be useful for finding the count of a single character, but for finding the count of multiple characters this approach would be inefficient as it would need to scan the input multiple times (once for 'a', once for 'b', etc).

Comment: oh, i missread, i thought it was for a single char... :P thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of 256 integers (on many platforms `char` is an 8-bit value). Since the number of times a character appears in a file can't be negative, an unsigned type makes sense.

```
unsigned charCount[256] = { 0 };
```

Each slot in the array represents the number of times the character with that value appears in that file.

```
while ((ch = fgetc(in_file)) != EOF)
{
    // increment the count of character ch
    charCount[ch]++;
}
```

When printing them out, some characters are not printable or are whitespace (this is particularly applicable if you are reading a binary file), you can use the `isprint` and `isspace` functions found in the `ctype.h` header.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    // only display characters with a count of at least 1
    if (charCount[i] > 0)
    {
        if (!isprint(i) || isspace(i))
            printf("%u instances of character %x\n", charCount[i], (unsigned) i);
        else
            printf("%u instances of character '%c'\n", charCount[i], i);
    }   
}
```