# Count number of 32-bit numbers in binary file

Tags: c, count, binary, bit

I am making a program where I should keep track of how many 32-bit numbers there are in a binary file.

For example when having as input a file that has in total 4x32 bits:
    01001001010010010010100101001011010010001001010010010010100101000101010001001001010010010001000101001010010001001001001000000000

It should print 4.

I tried this with `getc` but it didn't work.

I think the solution has to do with `fread` but I'm not sure how exactly to use it in this problem.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("/home/pavlos55/GitRepo/arm11_1415_testsuite/test_cases", "rb");
    uint32_t number;
    uint32_t lines = 0;

    while (fread(&number, 4, 1, fp)) {
        lines++;
    }
    printf("%i", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

Can `fread` be in the condition. Why isn't this enough?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19416047/c-character-count-from-a-file

Comment: Are you counting words or bytes? If you're counting bytes, as you say, the answer should be 16, not 4.

Comment: What is the problem with the code above, again?

Comment: And, is this bunch of zeros and ones actually what you have in your input file? I mean, is it what you see in a text editor when opening it?

Comment: @DoxyLover I actually did a mistake in the question, I'm not counting bytes, I'm counting double words (32 bits).

Comment: @EugeneSh. the binary file doesn't open in my text editor, but this is what I expect of a binary file. Is this wrong?

Comment: @pk163 Perfectly fine. Sometimes people don't understand the difference between bits and their ascii representation, so I wanted to make sure this is not the case here.

Comment: Why not just divide the size of the file by 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You switched the 3rd and 4th arguments to `fread()`: with a `uint32_t`, you can read 4 elements of size 1, not 1 element of size 4. This is important to make sense out of what `fread()` returns: the actual number of elements read - this is what you need to add to `lines`. Here's a working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp = fopen("test.c", "rb");
    uint32_t number;
    uint32_t lines = 0;
    size_t bytes_read;

    while ((bytes_read = fread(&number, 1, 4, fp))) {
        lines += bytes_read;
    }

    printf("%i\n", lines);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: To count the number of 32-bit numbers, just divide `lines` by 4 after the loop:

```
lines /= 4;
printf("%i\n", lines);
```

Answer (score 4):

A more pragmatic solution would be to `fseek()` to the end of the file, then use `ftell()` to obtain the resulting position. This will be "the size of the file in bytes."